# How to install poppler on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS so ActiveStorage can preview PDFs?

Tags: rails-activestorage

I have a Rails 6 app using ActiveStorage and ActionText.  When the user attaches a PDF, I would like an image preview to be generated automatically.

This works on my laptop (macOS) where I have poppler installed via Homebrew.

However it does not happen on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS production server.  Looking at Rails's source code, it seems I need the `pdftoppm` binary on the path.  I installed the `poppler-utils` package on the server, and that put `pdftoppm` on the path.

```
$ pdftoppm -v
pdftoppm version 0.62.0
Copyright 2005-2017 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

But now when I upload a PDF, I get an ActiveStorage::UnrepresentableError – even though `blob.representable?` is `true`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install poppler-utils
```

And then restart Puma so Rails sees poppler.